# I've looked at the Science involved but have doubts this would work, how can you generate momentum with-in a sealed system to produce propulsion?

Tags: propulsion, physics, magnetic-field

Could you use a magnetic super-capacitor compound which is charged so it gains the maximum amount of weight\mass then is pushed away from the main object down a chamber using a magnetic field. As the compound travels down through the chamber it is discharged then transported back to where it started using another magnetic field and\or combination of different processes.

The discharged (negatively charged) compound will have a lower weight\mass than the positively charged compound so we are effectively pushing out more than we transport back but as we will be transferring the energy from the charged compound (as it is being discharged) through copper cables to complete our system and charge the compound again before it's pushed away (from the main object) would that also apply weight\mass cancelling out any potential propulsion we've achieved (Newton's 3rd law)? Or would an electric charge applied to motionless cables not work in the same way?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I think this is either a "Will this perpetual motion idea work?" or a "Will this violation of conservation of momentum idea work?" question. While you tie it into Space Exploration I think it's strictly a question about Physics and not really on-topic in Space Exploration.

Comment: The force to move the particles back and forth within the system will balance out.

Comment: @uhoh: it's off-topic for physics SE (non-mainstream physics rule): I think it should also be off-topic here, but there does not seem to be a non-mainstream physics rule here, so ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think questions about mechanisms which involve violations of very basic physical laws (in this case momentum conservation) are off-topic.

Comment: @tfb I think this is just plain off topic: "This question is about other space sciences (physics, weather, astronomy, etc), **and does not directly pertain to space exploration as outlined in the help center**."

Comment: It's also remarkably similar to a question asked and closed in the recent past.